# Jetty server leaves behind threads after stop

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am working at a Scala project that used Jetty to serve webpages generated by a Scalatra servlet.

I am having troubles stopping the server. It shutdowns, but it leaves behind some threads that prevent my application from closing.

This is how I instantiate the server:

```
val server = new Server(8080)
val context = new WebAppContext()
context.setResourceBase("visualization")
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new CallTreeServlet(data)), "/callTree/*");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DataLoadingServlet(data)), "/data/*");
server.setHandler(context)
server
```

I start and stop it using the corresponding methods from the `sbt` console.
When I stop the server it correctly does not serve the pages anymore, but my application is still running because of some threads sill running.

Is there any way to force jetty and all its threads to stop?

You can find the complete log of the errors I get after the shutdown operation [here](http://pastebin.com/8brvkcDR)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a thread dump to say what threads are still running?

Note that this kind of thing is probably better reported in a bugzilla report rather than at stackoverflow.

Comment: Probably I will report it on bugzilla. In the meanwhile I solved by running my application as a standalone main with `sbt run-main MY_CLASS`